# Have jquery filter inside live event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this following code with jquery , so it will alternate colors on each row of a table:

```
  $("tr").filter(':nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('odd').next().addClass('even');
```

but unfortunately it doesnt work when the table comes from an ajax call .. is there a way to put this into a $("tr").live...   and make it work like that? .. I have tried different aproaches like this: ( I know the syntax may not be correct ).

```
$("tr").live({ 
 $("this").filter(':nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('odd').next().addClass('even')
});
```

But doestn seem to work

Comment: cant you run this code after you ajax has triggered?

Comment: `.live` is for events.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live` isn't a catch-all solution for problems that come from dynamic content. It only works with *events*.  Normally, you listen for events with `bind`; when your content is dynamic, `live` is a way to capture events reliably. So you need another solution for styles...

The simplest solution is to define your CSS using `nth-child`:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    // whatever the odd styles are
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
    // whatever the even styles are
}
```

This won't work in all browsers, since it's CSS3. (In particular, it won't work in Firefox 3 or Internet Explorer before version 9.)

The other solution is to update all the `tr` elements on the page after every AJAX call using [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('tr:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('odd').next().addClass('even');
});
```

This won't have great performance, but it probably won't be a particular drain as it will always happen asynchronously. This will, obviously, work cross-browser.

Comment: ok , I just though with live would be much easier  ;)  , thanks I will implemente the update ont he ajaxComplete way.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use the :odd and :even tags for example

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3KdCk/)